# GAS: trigger email whenever file is shared

Tags: google-apps-script, file-sharing

I had been hoping to allow some editors to share a sheet, and other editors not be allowed to share. It looks like the 'editors can/can't share' feature applies to all editors and can't be individualized. As a 2nd best solution, I'm wondering if I can at least get an email notification when the document is shared so I can keep an eye on access. Is there a way to trigger an email when a file is shared by anyone? Like 'onOpen' but for sharing.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38242684/can-i-trigger-a-google-script-when-a-file-is-saved-to-google-drive

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible with the Push Notifications API of Google Drive. See [this link](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push) for details.

- This answer originally proposed by @Amit Agarwal

> Please select this answer so that we can use it in future reference to this question because getting the moderators to change it is impossible. I guess they can't change things just because they happen to be wrong.