# How to trigger Google Apps Script on file creation in Google drive?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-drive-api

I'm just new to everything about this. I created an Apps Script Project just by inside a Google Drive folder, so I did not use a Spreadsheet to create the project.

I created a function that is, when the testfile.csv file is uploaded to Folder1, it will move to Folder2. Folder1 will become empty. This function is working fine.

However, I would like the function/script to automatically run when a new testfile.csv file is uploaded again to the Folder1. The test.csv file is uploaded once a day and it can be anytime of the day--no specific time or range.

I'm afraid the "Add Trigger" built-in to the Apps Script won't work in our situation as it will keep on running depends on the set time.

Hope someone can enlighten me. Thank you!

Comment: Pardon if I failed to understand your goal. But why you don't want a time triggered script? It can check the folder, say, every 60 seconds and to run if a new file was found inside the folder. As far as I know Drive has no "onLoad()" trigger.

Comment: There was an instance wherein we received an error like the user account is simultaneously running script or like too many times (not the exact error message though). I was thinking this is because my other Apps Script Projects are also set to time based triggers.

Comment: I'm not even sure if that was the cause of the error though. but, if time-based trigger should not be an issue while my other Script Projects are time-based triggers can be kept running then I think I can use the 60sec time trigger. I just really need an input from you guys who really have the knowledge about this. btw, thanks Yuri.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need [Drive API push notifications](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push) but sadly it can't trigger a google apps script. See a more detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67283488/16132436).

Your best solution is a time triggered script as what Yuri mentioned in the comments above.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I think time trigger is really my best chance.

Comment: No problem @cgstats. You are pretty much limited on your options. I suggest if you use time based trigger, make sure you make the frequency a little less so it won't error out since it has a limit per day. properly calculate how many times you can do your triggers daily