# Detect changes in private Google Drive folder with Google App Script

Tags: google-drive-api, shared-drive

The goal is to detect newly created Meet recording that are saved in a specific Drive folder on the private drive of an account. When a new file is detected it is then moved to a shared drive. All this with Google App Script.

I've looked around and found the following thread that is similar to what i'm looking for.
[Detect when a File has Been Uploaded to Google Drive in GAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67274965/detect-when-a-file-has-been-uploaded-to-google-drive-in-gas?newreg=28a90f746576440ea52feab483ce1ab2)

But is doesn't seem to be possible from what I understand. But that thread is a year old so something could have changed in the mean time. Unfortunately I'm not a dev and only have some basic programming skills so it take a bit of effort for me to get something running or even to understand what is going on.

Maybe someone has been struggling with the same thing they are trying to solve?

Comment: What about using puppeteerJS for watching a Google Drive folder? I have a method fully described for my own use case (which can be adapted for yours), so if you are interested, let me know.